# Fit a sinusoidal function to my data in python

Tags: python, trigonometry

So I am trying to fit a simple and periodic sin function to my data. I am following several scripts available, like this one https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_curve_fit.html. It seems very simple but it is not working. I do not have any experience with python but I think it is the simplest way to do what I want.

Basically I have a two column file, with nth rows, like this:

```
52.9702 3.0341
56.0391 3.4201
76.2522 2.4429
80.1405 2.7961
80.0317 2.7740
75.0725 2.6012
344.162 2.9836
42.7086 2.4734
42.5988 2.5443
41.265 2.4942
11.6206 2.8711
11.0102 2.8349
17.4789 2.9342
77.6126 3.0262
230.322 2.8210
231.012 2.5993
226.29 3.4871
196.96 2.7132
193.002 3.1390
191.07 3.0209
195.551 2.7216
296.402 2.4987
289.057 2.5671
2.13451 2.1597
1.85383 2.8615
```

Because I am not used to python I decided to use a very simple code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
file=open("test.txt","r")
x_data = np.loadtxt("test.txt")[:,0]
y_data = np.loadtxt("test.txt")[:, 1]
#Just to check my data distribution
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o', color ='red', label ="data")
plt.show()
def test_func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.sin(b * f)
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data, p0=[2, 2])
print(params)
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, test_func(x_data, params[0], params[1]), label='Fitted function')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

As you can see in my data plot, I still have to remove some outliers, yet I was trying to make this work.
[image: plot of my data]

My problem is this:

```
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data, p0=[2, 2])
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is probably very basic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not used x within your function.

Comment: I don't get a syntax error when I run this code. Please double-check whether the code in the post matches what you are running.

Comment: Once you fix the `f` → `x` typo, the program runs without error and does a fit (with the provided sample data the results are nonsensical though).

Comment: @jpf I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: I really can not find the problem. I still have the syntax error even though I correcter the x.